# Access WC() to get cart content in ajax callback

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to get woocommerce cart content in ajax callback function but it returns empty.

I've also tried using global $woocommerce variable that also returns the same result. I'm trying to get the cart content and convert all product to autoship feature. I'm using wooautoship plugin for that. however, main query is, how to get the cart details in ajax callback.

My Code is as follow:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'woo_cart_autoship_js', 99);
function woo_cart_autoship_js(){
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function($){
                $(document).on('click', '#convert-to-autoship', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.post( "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>", { action: "convert-to-autoship" })
                      .done(function( data ) {
                        alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
                      });
                });
            })(jQuery);
        </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_convert-to-autoship', 'convert_to_autoship', 99 );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_convert-to-autoship', 'convert_to_autoship', 99 );
function convert_to_autoship(){
    print_r(WC()->cart->get_cart());
    wp_die();
}
```

Comment: for me its working if I remove - and _ from ajax call action